# Python Folium Choropleth Map - Legend Quantiles Overlap

Tags: python, data-visualization, folium, choropleth

I am struggling to solve a problem I am having with folium choropleth map. I am visualizing COVID-19 cases and try to plot the colour according to their quantiles affiliation. However, unfortunately, the legend overlaps. Hence, I am wondering if someone could please tell me how to fix this problem? Either by "logarithmically" scaling the legend or just showing the start and end. Unfortunately, I did not find sufficient advice online. Please find below the code and a visualization:

```
myscale = (covid_cases['total_cases'].quantile((0,0.02,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.9,0.98,1))).tolist()

m = folium.Map([10, -10], zoom_start= 2)

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data = world_countries,
    data = covid_cases,
    columns = ['code','total_cases'],
    nan_fill_color = 'gray',
    nan_fill_opacity = 0.20,
    key_on = 'feature.id',
    fill_color='YlGnBu',
    threshold_scale=myscale,
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=1.0,
    legend_name='COVID-19 Total Cases per Country | Data Source: OurWorldInData (own repr.)',
).add_to(m)


m.save(os.path.join('/Users/XXX/Results', 'covid_cases.html'))
```

[image: Overlapping legend]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you find a fix for it? I am also having some issues with the overlapping labels

Comment: Hey @LucianNut, no, unfortunately not until now. Did you?

Comment: I applied a logarithm to the values such that the spread between the values is not too large and it's ok now. I have seen that some people who want to keep the initial values are creating a custom legend with equal distances between the different values in the legend, but it's way too complicated for such a task

Answer (score 0):

A different way to solve this problem:

```
    myscale = np.linspace(covid_cases['total_cases'].min(), covid_cases['total_cases'].max(), 6)
```

6 is the number of clases or "different colors" that you want.